# Adding keybord shortcut for AUCTeX in Emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

*Disclaimer: This is a question about Emacs and AUCTeX.  Sorry if this is out of the scope of tex.sx.*

**How can I add a new command to AUCTeX?**

I want my AUCTeX mode to have the command `C-c C-f C-p` insert a `\pname{ }` and behave similarly to the other ways of changing fonts, e.g. `C-c C-f C-e` for `\emph{ }`.

The manual page [Changing the font](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/auctex_19.html), explains that

> AUCTeX provides convenient keyboard shortcuts for inserting macros which specify the font to be used for typesetting certain parts of the text. They start with `C-c C-f`, and the last `C-` combination tells AUCTeX which font you want

```
Font list:   KEY        TEXTFONT           MATHFONT

         C-a                          \mathcal{ }  
         C-b        \textbf{ }         \mathbf{ }  
         C-c        \textsc{ }                     
         C-e          \emph{ }                     
         C-f        \textsf{ }         \mathsf{ }  
         TAB        \textit{ }         \mathit{ }  
         RET        \textmd{ }                     
         C-n    \textnormal{ }     \mathnormal{ }  
         C-r        \textrm{ }         \mathrm{ }  
         C-s        \textsl{ }         \mathbb{ }  
         C-t        \texttt{ }         \mathtt{ }  
         C-u        \textup{ }                     
         C-d  -- delete font
```

I want to bind the command `C-c C-f C-p` to `\pname{ }` in AUCTeX mode.

Comment: Not completely inappropriate, but there is now an [emacs](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) site.  It's still beta, too, so it could use the traffic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AUCTeX actually makes this very easy: customize `LaTeX-font-list`.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-font-list
  '(?\C-p "\\pname{" "}"))
```

should work.  You'll have to re-run `LaTeX-mode` in the appropriate buffers if you have any open.

---

Note that this *must* be done *after* `LaTeX-font-list` has been defined in `latex.el`.  Here is a simple configuration with [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package):

```lisp
(use-package latex
  :ensure auctex
  :config
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-font-list
               '(?\C-p "\\pname{" "}")))
```

Comment: Whoa. That's a cool-looking package!

Comment: @jon It is pretty neat :) Simplified my config like you wouldn't believe.